# HTML - Get data for each button

Tags: html

I'm trying to have a login and register button, when the login button gets clicked I want to specify it's a login action and when it's a register action I want to specify that in the URL. Is there some sort of attribute to define default get data which is always in there URL (plus the input data)?

This is my current code:

```
        <form class="login-form" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get" action="php/login.php">
            <input class="login-element credential" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"/>
            <button class="login-element button" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="login-element button" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="login-form" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get"  action="php/login.php">
        <input class="login-element credential" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"/>
        <button class="login-element button" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
        <button class="login-element button" name="register" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
```

in login.php file your code goes like this.

```
       if(isset($_POST['login']))
       {
          //your code goes here...
       }
   else
   {
    //your code goes here...
   }


   if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
     //your code goes here...
    }
    else
    {
      //your code goes here...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'data' attribute to each button and then change the 'action' of the form based on that. e.g:

```
<button class="login-element button" type="submit" data-action="login">Login</button>
<button class="login-element button" type="submit" data-action="register">Register</button>
```

You can 'grab' the data attribute in jQuery as follows:

```
$('.login-element').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).date('action');
    if(action == "register"){
         // -- do register stuff
    }else{
         // -- do login stuff
    };
});
```